# C++: Overloaded virtual called via derived class, results in NULL call / segmentation fault

Tags: c++, inheritance, segmentation-fault, virtual-functions

## ETA:

I finally got around to running the same code on a different machine, and it **works just fine**. I'm actually not quite sure what machine it originaly was, might have been a linux notebook or a macbook air. This time around, it's some hosted virtual machine running debian.

It almost looks like I actually hit an obscure compiler or hardware bug there, as strange and impossible as it sounds. Not worth any further investigation though, methinks.

## Original question:

I have a weekend-project / toy widget set.

There's a virtual function *calculateContentRect()* in base class *Widget* that gets called from a non-virtual function *calculateRects()* in *Widget* to calculate some rectangle. The virtual function is then overridden in derived class *Window* (but not in further-derived class *PopupMenu*).

When I instantiate *Widget* or *Window*, everything is fine. However, if I instantiate a *PopupMenu*, the call to *calculateContentRect()* from *calculateRect()* fails, and gdb shows me that it is trying to call NULL - something along the lines of (gdb):

```
#0  0x0000000000000000 in Window::calculateContentRect()
#1  0xWHATEVER         in Widget::calculateRects()
```

Note that this is not a base class pointer. It all happens on the stack.

I wasn't able to isolate and reproduce the bug, but I can't well paste the bloody whole project here, so I'm trying to cut the relevant parts...

So, here's the simplified code fragment:

```
class Widget {
    protected:
        void calculateRects() { ... calculateContentRect(); }
        virtual void calculateContentRect() { ... }
};

class FocusableContainer: public Widget { ... };

class Window: public FocusableContainer {
    protected:
        virtual void calculateContentRect() { ... }
};

class PopupMenu: public Window {
    public:
        void pack() { ... calculateRects(); ... }
};

int main() {
    PopupMenu pm(...);
    pm.pack();
}
```

In short, I think/hope that the following would be some relevant questions:

- Is it even theoretically possible that an improperly constructed objects results in such behaviour (I'm fairly certain this isn't the case, but who knows...)?
- Does visibility at all play into this? The functions calling each other are all protected.
- As the error only happens in a call on a derived-derived object (Widget > Window > PopupMenu), does that necessarily mean that the error lies in PopupMenu?
- **How can en entry in a vtable ever be 0x0?**

Comment: I can see the problem. It's in one of your `...` bits of code sections...

Comment: Running this code with empty method implementations runs fine in Visual Studio 2010. I guess the error is somewhere in the `...` parts you did not post. You probably do an invalid type cast somewhere.

Comment: Mats Petersson: Yeah, most probably. Of course, the issue is how to find the bits that are relevant so I can post them here. But then, if I was able to do that, I wouldn't have to ask stackoverflow... so yeah.

I'm actually hoping that someone has an abstract explanation for possible causes of a call to 0x0 via a vtable. Maybe I can derive the actual issue from that.

Comment: Generally, the principle is that you try to cut out as much as possible of the code that "doesn't cause the problem", until you are left with a few lines of code that does produce the problem - ideally as a complete program that can be run on "any" platform.

Comment: Mats Petersson: True true, thanks for the reminder. Of course, I'm a lazy horse and hold laziness as a virtue. :-)

The moment I find this bug will be one of either complete bedazzlement or utter fulfillment. Or both. In any case, I'll be sure to post the answer here once I find it.

Comment: Mats Petersson: It gets funnier. I finally got around to running the same code on a different machine, and it works just fine. I'm actually not quite sure what machine it originaly was, might have been a linux notebook or a macbook air. This time around, it's some hosted virtual machine running debian.

Answer (score 1):

I got into the same kind of problem. Clean/Rebuild helped me. I know this is simple and stupid, but it took half of a day for me to try this simple operation. This most probably will not help the author, but maybe can save some time for others junior developers.

The mechanism, as I understand it, is when I have changed some function to virtual in the ancestor class, the child class is not changed, thus is not rebuilt and finally no vtable is created.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you're calling calculateRects from the constructor of a base class in which the virtual function is still pure virtual.

Calling a virtual function from a base class constructor results in a call to the virtual function as specified in that base class (the derived class's virtual function cannot be used because the derived object is not yet complete). In the case of a pure virtual function this means trying to call a function pointed to by the null pointer.

Comment: please be aware of the OP's question point(s) and do elaborate your answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm FAIRLY certain that's not the case (it was my first guess, too), but I'll definitely re-check that.